# The declared package "" does not match the expected package "src"

Tags: java

I get this error in Atom editor. First time I've encountered it and now it's showing on all my java files.
How do i get rid of this?

Comment: by correcting your package statements

Answer (score 3):

In java, packages have to match directory structure, and that goes for both class files and source (java) files. So, if you have:

```
package foo.bar;

public class Baz {}
```

Then the java file must be at `/X/foo/bar/Baz.java` and if you want to run it as a class file, it must be at `/X/foo/bar/Baz.class`, where X is whatever you want and is considered 'the root' - X is what you would put on your classpath, for example. Not `/X/foo/bar`.

You've got the reverse situation: You've told the atom editor that, say, `/Users/home/Corvo/workspace/CorvosProject` is the root, and your source file is at `/Users/home/Corvo/workspace/CorvosProject/src/Hello.java`. Your `Hello.java` file contains no package statement at all (which is something you want to address at some point later). Relative to the root, the file is therefore at `src/Hello.java`, and hence the error. You don't actually want to fix it by putting `package src;` in the file - that makes no sense, package names are supposed to describe the product/library/application as well as the owner/author, and `src` is therefore entirely inappropriate. The fix is instead to tell Atom that the 'root source directory' is not `/Users/home/Corvo/workspace/CorvosProject`, but `/Users/home/Corvo/workspace/CorvosProject/src`.

Hunt around in the configuration screen, or perhaps check if you can right click on folders to configure them as source roots; if that's the case, unset `/Users/home/Corvo/workspace/CorvosProject`, and set `/Users/home/Corvo/workspace/CorvosProject/src` (java projects can have more than one source root folder, hence why you may be able to set this on a per-folder basis).

Atom uses eclipse under the hood, and eclipse projects can have any number of source roots.

Comment: No; you already have a folder named 'src'. Tell Atom that it is your source folder.

Comment: How do i do that?